# Simple Array Formula in Excel not comparing the right values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I'm trying to calculate with an Array Formula (in Cell D2) what i'm calculating in cell D11. The issue i'm having is that it appears my Array Formula is not evaluating the inputted array one-by-one. As an example, I want the second comparison that the formula does to be the following:

Check if ([B7>0] AND [C7=0]) and, if so, return D7.

But I think it's only checking to see if every value in the column B array is >0 and if every value in the column C array is =0.

The screenshot below details my problem. Thanks!

Here is the array formula: `{SUM(IF(AND(B6:B10>0,C6:C10=0),B6:B10,0))}`

[image: Pic of my formulas]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1395033/edit) to provide your formula as text -- it will save everyone the effort of retyping them. That said, you may want to look into `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS`.

Comment: `SUMIFS(B6:B10,B6:B10,">0",C6:C10,0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott Craner said in his comment you can use SUMIFS.

```
=SUMIFS(B6:B10, B6:B10,">"&0, C6:C10,0)
```

This will SUM the values in B6:B10 where the rows match all of the following criteria. Here's a screenshot of it in action:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that there are ways to do it without Array Formulas, but i'm using this example as an exercise to help me learn Array Formulas. How would I go about using Array Formulas to solve this?

Comment: if you are adamant about using an array formula you can use this:   SUM(IF(B6:B10>0,IF(C6:C10=0,B6:B10,0),0)) it works by only passing rows that meat the first IF criteria into the second IF statement

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the non-array formula:

```
=SUM((B6:B10>0)*(C6:C10=0)*(C6:C10))
```

(with multiplication sign between parenthesis)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you please give more detail into what your suggested solution is? As you provided it, I can't type that into excel because the inputs for the sum function aren't values (at least that's what my Excel error message suggests.)


EDIT: This is the output (#VALUE!) i'm getting: https://i.imgur.com/A54oMuw.png

Answer (score 0):

`SUMPRODUCT` may be what you're looking for:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B6:B10>0),--(C6:C10=0),B6:B10)
```

With your data, it returns `45`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that there are ways to do it without Array Formulas, but i'm using this example as an exercise to help me learn Array Formulas. How would I go about using Array Formulas to solve this?